# Why is Azure Web App Service unable to find ng in the docker container it is running?

Tags: angular, azure, npm, azure-web-app-service, github-actions

Trying to deploy a basic web-app to Azure Web App Services, and it doesn't seem to be working. Am seeing this error:

```
2019-12-27T23:37:42.634461405Z   _____                               
2019-12-27T23:37:42.634500106Z   /  _  \ __________ _________   ____  
2019-12-27T23:37:42.634511007Z  /  /_\  \___   /  |  \_  __ \_/ __ \ 
2019-12-27T23:37:42.634520107Z /    |    \/    /|  |  /|  | \/\  ___/ 
2019-12-27T23:37:42.634528407Z \____|__  /_____ \____/ |__|    \___  >
2019-12-27T23:37:42.634536708Z         \/      \/                  \/ 
2019-12-27T23:37:42.634544908Z A P P   S E R V I C E   O N   L I N U X
2019-12-27T23:37:42.634553008Z 
2019-12-27T23:37:42.634560609Z Documentation: http://aka.ms/webapp-linux
2019-12-27T23:37:42.634568609Z NodeJS quickstart: https://aka.ms/node-qs
2019-12-27T23:37:42.634576709Z NodeJS Version : v12.13.0
2019-12-27T23:37:42.634584609Z Note: Any data outside '/home' is not persisted
2019-12-27T23:37:42.634592610Z 
2019-12-27T23:37:43.144384283Z Oryx Version: 0.2.20191105.2, Commit: 67e159d71419415435cb5d10c05a0f0758ee8809, ReleaseTagName: 20191105.2
2019-12-27T23:37:43.147834617Z Cound not find build manifest file at '/home/site/wwwroot/oryx-manifest.toml'
2019-12-27T23:37:43.148467642Z Could not find operation ID in manifest. Generating an operation id...
2019-12-27T23:37:43.149091266Z Build Operation ID: c4f7694f-d5bc-4452-8bb2-c1e800f2d0e7
2019-12-27T23:37:44.402401478Z Environment Variables for Application Insight's Codeless Configuration exists..
2019-12-27T23:37:44.706186461Z Writing output script to '/opt/startup/startup.sh'
2019-12-27T23:37:45.084946652Z Running #!/bin/sh
2019-12-27T23:37:45.086758923Z 
2019-12-27T23:37:45.086778423Z # Enter the source directory to make sure the script runs where the user expects
2019-12-27T23:37:45.088001471Z cd "/home/site/wwwroot"
2019-12-27T23:37:45.088021272Z 
2019-12-27T23:37:45.088921606Z export NODE_PATH=$(npm root --quiet -g):$NODE_PATH
2019-12-27T23:37:45.088941007Z if [ -z "$PORT" ]; then
2019-12-27T23:37:45.089756039Z      export PORT=8080
2019-12-27T23:37:45.089778440Z fi
2019-12-27T23:37:45.090585971Z 
2019-12-27T23:37:45.090603272Z export NODE_OPTIONS='--require ./oryx-appinsightsloader.js ' $NODE_OPTIONS
2019-12-27T23:37:45.091407503Z npm start
2019-12-27T23:37:48.809993637Z 
2019-12-27T23:37:48.810043739Z > angular-todo@0.0.0 start /home/site/wwwroot
2019-12-27T23:37:48.810054439Z > ng serve
2019-12-27T23:37:48.810063040Z 
2019-12-27T23:37:48.866439626Z /home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/.bin/ng: 1: /home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/.bin/ng: ../@angular/cli/bin/ng: not found
2019-12-27T23:37:48.872441959Z npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2019-12-27T23:37:48.874125524Z npm ERR! syscall spawn
2019-12-27T23:37:48.889093905Z npm ERR! file sh
2019-12-27T23:37:48.890656766Z npm ERR! errno ENOENT
2019-12-27T23:37:48.893052158Z npm ERR! angular-todo@0.0.0 start: `ng serve`
2019-12-27T23:37:48.894167002Z npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
2019-12-27T23:37:48.899168996Z npm ERR! 
2019-12-27T23:37:48.899931925Z npm ERR! Failed at the angular-todo@0.0.0 start script.
2019-12-27T23:37:48.901243776Z npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

It looks like the docker image doesn't have ng available in it.

I'm using GitHub actions to build and deploy the app, so I don't have access to the docker container itself to alias commands. Any help would be appreciated.

Source code here:
https://github.com/pbansal-seattleu/angular-todo

Website is hosted here:
http://pbansal-todo.azurewebsites.net/

Answer (score 0):

First of all: the Angular CLI is a development tool, not a production tool. You should have a build pipeline that builds your application, then a release pipeline to release the output to your App Service.

It's not a good idea to install and run Agular CLI in production. One of the reasons is that `ng serve` uses `webpack-dev-server`. This is a development server and is not meant to be used for production.

Also:

> you do not want to use ng serve in production even if you use the --prod flag.
>
> The reason that flag exists is to mimic the compilation steps of a production build in a dev environment locally to ease your development process if you so desire.
>
> Summary: use ng serve for development with or without --prod and use a production ready web server for deployments.

*Taken from [is ng serve --prod a good choice for deployment?](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5274)*

For more information on how to deploy, see the [Angular - Deployment documentation](https://angular.io/guide/deployment).

By the way: if you need a tool like Angular CLI on a machine, you should install it using for instance `npm install`.